# How to add documents to mongo only if they don't exist

Tags: mongodb

Have been reading a lot about this issue but it doesn't seem there is something matching my requirements.
Having this schema:

```
const TestSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        identifier: {type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    }
);
```

I add new documents this way:

```
db.tests.insertMany(
    [
        {name: 'product 1', identifier: 'abc'}
        ,{name: 'product 2', identifier: 'def'}
        ,{name: 'product 3', identifier: 'abc'}
    ]
);
```

The field "identifier" is unique. I can declare it as "unique" so no duplicates will be added. However, this will throw errors which to me does not seem to be a good practice, even if the final result is correct.

Using upsert could be the solution. However, I cannot find a flag for "insertMany" to just upsert.
Moreover, upserting is not relaly what I want. I just want to skip  "product 3" above because the identifier already exist.

So in my case, I don't think "unique" or "upsert" is exactly what I am looking for. Is there some other solution?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the errors. But you should use `{ordered:false}` as an option

Answer (score 2):

Putting it on a `try .. catch` statement would help you resolve the errors and will just insert the first unique item from your `Test` document occurrence.

If you want to identify which item has a duplicate `identifier` you can get that from the error message in the catch block.

```
try {
    db.tests.insertMany(
        [
             {_id: 'abc', name: 'product 1', identifier: 'abc'}
            ,{_id: 'def', name: 'product 2', identifier: 'def'}
            ,{_id: 'abc', name: 'product 3', identifier: 'abc'}
        ]
    );

} catch (e) {
    print(e.message.match(/\d+/)[0]) // 2
}
```

This will insert the first two documents and will print the index `2` which is a duplicate in this case.

**AND NOTE**

I've added `_id` with value same as the `identifier`
If the document does not specify an `_id` field, then `mongod` adds the `_id` field and assign a unique ObjectId for the document.